# How to enforce method interface with Python?

Tags: python, types, dynamic-typing, static-typing

I want to create a class that requires a specific method, with specifically typed arguments and return values. 
I can inherit from an abstract class that requires the method to be implemented - but I do not have the ability to force specific argument values and return values ala a static language like Java (I could throw an error at runtime if I wanted to). What is the best way of approaching this with Python? Have looked into type hinting a bit but I don't think it solves this problem.

Comment: If you are really needing this you can check out MyPy: http://mypy-lang.org/ but I don't think this functionality exists in CPython. Type hinting is the closest thing.

Comment: yeah I wasn't sure if it was possible. I thought MyPy is what type hinting in Python 3 got based on? Or maybe they only ported part of it

Comment: You're right, PEP-484 is based on MyPy. I'm afraid you're using the wrong language if you want parameter typing enforced at runtime. Python simply does not do that, short of adding explicit `isinstance` checks to the method.

Comment: If you are looking for a runtime signature validation of your methods, you can check https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce module. However, it is not intended for making Java out of Python and it is still far from being a production ready library. Please be careful!

Answer (score 1):

This seems fundamentally un-pythonic.  There's no typing of function parameters in python, so there's no way to restrict the argument types to a function.

Type hinting is useful for documentation or code linters, but python doesn't use that information to enforce anything at runtime.

If you really want to ensure the validity of an interface (even beyond just argument types), the way to do that would be with functional unittests.

Unittesting and Test-Driven Development are so prevalent in the python community that type-hinting doesn't really add much when it comes to testing and finding bugs.  And while it's a debatable point, there are many who believe that any benefit from type-hinting is immediately destroyed by making python code harder to read.  There are some promising possibilities with type-hinting of being able to compile python out to C or Java, but they don't exist, yet.

Comment: Doesn't the mypy utility compile it and check for issues before runtime? Or am I misunderstanding it

Comment: mypy can test a closed system.  It can check that, internally, within your code, you're not calling a function with incorrect data types.  If you're writing a python package that others will use, it obviously can't test for that, so it's still not enforcing any types.  If you do define type hints in your code, it means others using your library can run mypy on their own code and maybe get some type warnings.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking to do anything in run-time; he says "I can throw in run-time if I wanted to", but it seems in the sense that it's easy. He seems to wants *static* time check. And PEP 484 / mypy provide exactly that: if you define a class to have typed abstract methods, subclasses would not pass the type check if they have the wrong arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure how adding type hints can make python harder to read. When reading other developers' code, it's really difficult to understand what's going on unless variables are named with their types included like `list_of_integers`, there's a name for that and I can't remember what it is.

In addition to this, type-hinting allows IDEs to provide better code-prediction and error-checking.